# Bash alias not working for "cd" command in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, alias

Trying alias in Bash, not able to see it working in conjunction with `cd` command

```
[0s][/nobackup/sumikum7]> sjc-tftp
-bash: /auto/tftp-xeinfra/sumikum7/: Is a directory
[0s][/nobackup/sumikum7]> cd sjc-tftp
-bash: cd: sjc-tftp: No such file or directory
[0s][/nobackup/sumikum7]> cd /auto/tftp-xeinfra/sumikum7/
[0s][/auto/tftp-xeinfra/sumikum7]>
```

Tried searching few places, but don't find this issue mentioned anywhere for Linux.

Note:

- bash version : GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
- Found [something](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240542/cant-cd-into-alias) for MAC, lemme kindly know if this is the reason here as well.

Comment: Possible dulpicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958567/how-to-make-an-alias-for-a-long-path/39839346.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the bash man page:

**Aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the first word of a simple command.**

As `sjc-tftp` is not the first word in `cd sjc-tftp` it won't be expanded.  To achieve what you are attempting you could use a simple shell variable `$sjc-tftp` or make the alias include the cd command eg: `alias sjc-tftp="cd /auto/tftp-xeinfra/sumikum7/"`.  Then just type `sjc-tftp` on its own without the cd to change directory.  The Mac question you link to seems to be talking about symlinks rather than aliases.

Comment: Thanks, William.. it was really what I needed. I am using the ```full version``` now as you suggested!